# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, server

I am trying to save details in MongoDB and I am returning the response using the "return" statement yet I am getting the error. Can someone please help me out? I tried it using async-await as well but no luck!

```
const votedOnSolModel = require("../../models/votedOnSolModel");
const userProfileModel = require("../../models/userProfileModel");
const solutionModel = require("../../models/solutionModel");
exports.votingPost = async (req, res, next) => {
  userProfileModel.findOne({ githubId: req.body.githubId }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);

    if (doc) {
      var newVote = new votedOnSolModel({
        publicAddress: req.body.publicAddress,
        amountStaked: req.body.amountStaked,
        timeStamp: req.body.timeStamp,
        weightage: req.body.amountStaked,
        amountToBeReturned: 0,
        solutionId: req.body.solutionId,
        voterId: doc.voterId,
      });
      newVote
        .save()
        .then((newdoc) => {
          userProfileModel
            .updateOne(
              {
                githubId: req.body.githubId,
              },
              { $push: { votedOn: newdoc._id } }
            )
            .then((result) => {
              solutionModel
                .updateOne(
                  {
                    _id: req.body.solutionId,
                  },
                  {
                    $push: { votedOn: newdoc._id },
                  }
                )
                .then((finalResult) => {
                  res.sendStatus(201);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  return res.status(400).send(error);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              return res.status(400).send(error);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return res.status(400).send(error);
        });
    }
  });
};
```

This is the controller.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const { votingPost } = require("../controller/voting/votingPost");
const { voterDetailPost } = require("../controller/voting/voterDetailsPost");

router.post("/save", votingPost);
router.post("/voterDetails", voterDetailPost);

module.exports = router;
```

This is the router

My req.body

> {
> "publicAddress":"asdas",    "amountStaked":2,    "timeStamp":1233,    "solutionId":"rp1.com",    "githubId":"akp111"
> }

Kindly suggest me what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to follow your code because you have a whole bunch of non-connected promise chains (that are nested, not linked) and that makes error handling and returns a lot more difficult to implement and leads to lots of duplicate error handling code.  So, rather than try to identify exactly where things went wrong in that more difficult model, I've significantly simplified the code so the control flow is simpler to see and control.

Guidelines in this simplification:

1. Catch errors that all send the same result in one place.
2. No separate promise chains that aren't linked together.
3. Use `await` to make the control flow simpler.
4. Don't mix `await` and `.then()`
5. Don't mix plain asynchronous callbacks and promises.  Use the promise implementation for all database calls.
6. Use `const` and `let`, not `var`.

As a result of the simplification, the control flow for both success and error should be much simpler so when there's an error, it's easier to send the error response and be done and when there is no error, the flow is also simpler.

Here is that implementation:

```
const votedOnSolModel = require("../../models/votedOnSolModel");
const userProfileModel = require("../../models/userProfileModel");
const solutionModel = require("../../models/solutionModel");

exports.votingPost = async (req, res, next) => {
    let doc;
    try {
        doc = await userProfileModel.findOne({ githubId: req.body.githubId });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send(e);
        return;
    }
    if (!doc) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
        return;
    }
    try {
        const newVote = new votedOnSolModel({
            publicAddress: req.body.publicAddress,
            amountStaked: req.body.amountStaked,
            timeStamp: req.body.timeStamp,
            weightage: req.body.amountStaked,
            amountToBeReturned: 0,
            solutionId: req.body.solutionId,
            voterId: doc.voterId,
        });
        const newDoc = await newVote.save();
        await userProfileModel.updateOne({ githubId: req.body.githubId }, { $push: { votedOn: newdoc._id } });
        await solutionModel.updateOne({ _id: req.body.solutionId }, { $push: { votedOn: newdoc._id } });
        res.sendStatus(201);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
}
```

It occurs to me that if you get an error updating the `solutionModel`, then you may have an incomplete state because you've already updated the `userProfileModel`, but not updated the `solutionModel`.  You'd have to decide if you need special error handling for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You calling `send` and `status` always on the same response object. Obviously, that's not going to work. Add debug statements to your calls to see where you're trying to call `send` or `status` a second time.

I'd make `(err, doc) => {}` an async function, it'll be much easier to follow the logic. If you insist on callbacks, I'd rewrite is as follows for clarity because `res.send()` has no return value:

```
   res.status(400).send(error);
   return;
```